# Duplicate entries from database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, left-join, duplicate-data

**ON closer inspection the problem is solved if I remove the comment table join, but obviously this isn't ideal help appreciated!!**

I'm trying to write a blog with Codeigniter. At the moment i'm displaying all the information that I want to display, but for some reason, when viewing the blog, I've got duplicate content for the categories. There are only 3 test categories in my database but 1 of my test posts that has all 3 selected is showing six and the other is showing just the one category twice.

Even stranger than that, the first blog post is also counting the wrong number of comments. It's displaying 6 when there are only 4 in the database and only two are related to that post, but the strangest of all is that the second post displays the correct number of comments, two. How can that be.

This is the query from the model in question.

```
$this->db->select('posts.id,
                        posts.title,
                        posts.slug,
                        posts.content,
                        posts.author,
                        posts.date,
                        posts.time,
                        posts.tags,
                        posts.status,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name SEPARATOR \'-\') AS categories,
                        count(comments.id) as total_comments
                        ');
    $this->db->group_by(array('posts.id'));
    $this->db->join('posts_categories', 'posts_categories.blog_entry_id = posts.id', 'left outer', 'left outer');
    $this->db->join('categories', 'posts_categories.blog_category_id = categories.category_id', 'left outer');
    $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.post_id = posts.id', 'left outer' );

    $query = $this->db->get('posts', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
```

The standard query generated is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `posts`.`id`, 
`posts`.`title`, `posts`.`slug`, 
`posts`.`content`, `posts`.`author`, 
`posts`.`date`, `posts`.`time`, 
`posts`.`tags`, `posts`.`status`, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name SEPARATOR '-') AS categories, 
 count(comments.id) as total_comments 
 FROM (`posts`) 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts_categories` ON `posts_categories`.`blog_entry_id` = `posts`.`id` 
 LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `posts_categories`.`blog_category_id` = `categories`.`category_id` 
 LEFT JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` 
 GROUP BY `posts`.`id` LIMIT 1
```

The database dump can be found [here](http://jonigale.com/sql-dump.txt)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is making me crazy!

Cheers.

Comment: Have you run this query manually against your database?

Comment: as Brendan said, try to run the generated query directly in mysql, look at the result, and this may help you deduce the error assuming you know sql (you can get the generated query through $this->db->last_query()). consider removing the count so you know which fields it is counting. This is most likely an sql error. Also consider using "$this->db->distinct();" to avoid duplicate results.

Comment: ran this directly on my database and am getting the same errors, so clearly a problem with my query. Will have to try and rethink it. and idea's would be appreciated though @Brendan @death_relic0!

Comment: this is the query in question
    SELECT DISTINCT `posts`.`id`, `posts`.`title`, `posts`.`slug`, `posts`.`content`, `posts`.`author`, `posts`.`date`, `posts`.`time`, `posts`.`tags`, `posts`.`status`, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name SEPARATOR '-') AS categories, count(comments.id) as total_comments FROM (`posts`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts_categories` ON `posts_categories`.`blog_entry_id` = `posts`.`id` LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `posts_categories`.`blog_category_id` = `categories`.`category_id` LEFT JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` GROUP BY `posts`.`id` LIMIT 1

Comment: You're probably going to need to provide a sql dump to get help with this since it's pretty specific.

Comment: way to painful to copy into the comments, will upload a text file

Comment: [Sql dump](http://jonigale.com/sql-dump.txt)

Comment: @Brendan i've discovered that by removing the comments join the problem is sorted, but obviously that's not ideal, but was hoping it may give you some insight to assist?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any qualms running another query to get the comment count? You can do the following query (assuming Active Record):

```php
$this->db->where('parent_id', $post_id);
$this->db->count_all_results('comments');
```

This would have to be run for each post, though, so your # of queries would be n+1 where n = number of posts.

Comment: i'd prefer not to have to do that for each post, this is the controller for the blog roll so in theory could have any number of posts on the page and I wouldn't wan't to have to run a separate query for each. The problem appears to be in the comments join, if I remove that join then I get the correct return from the categories (i.e results aren't doubled), whereas if I include it, even without the count for comments [I get this](http://jonigale.com/example.rtf)

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran the query in your question against the SQL dump you provided and got only 2 rows, but there were only 2 comments with parent_ids that associated with a post id.

Comment: yea the query should return both the blog entries in the database but the problem arises in the categories and comments column, both of these are outputting the wrong data. I've looked into how wordpress run there queries and seen that they keep a total_comments in the posts database itself, so I think i'm just going to do that, I mean if it's good enough for wordpress then it's probably going to be good enough for me! Cheers for your help anyway